# visual studio c# does not build files that were change by pre-build event

Tags: c#, pre-build-event

I have solution in visual studio 2010 c#.
In the pre build event I execute command that change files in this solution.
The updated file is not built in the current build.
How can I do that the file, with the changes, will be built in the current build???

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know the files are not built? what is your indication?

Comment: Can you provide some information about what exactly are doing in pre build event? I can take a look in few hours and try to reproduce this

Comment: Thanks very much in advance. what I am trying to do is to write the time of the build into one of the solution files. than when the application run - clicking on some button will retrieve this information. please tell me if I was not clear enough, and thanks again.

Comment: is it a `cs` file? if not, what is the type of the file?

Comment: yes it's a cs file (assemlyInfo file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, it seems i figured out your issue.

I have set up a simple Console app and this event:

```
<PreBuildEvent>copy "D:\Program.cs" "D:\Projects\PreBuildFileModification\FileModification\Program.cs" /Y</PreBuildEvent>
```

And alas, this does not work! (copy happens and updates file on disk, but Visual Studio does not detect these changes and loads cached file).

Solution is to add:

```
<UseHostCompilerIfAvailable>false</UseHostCompilerIfAvailable>
```

In your configuration, eg:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
  <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
  <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  <UseHostCompilerIfAvailable>false</UseHostCompilerIfAvailable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And now this works like a charm.

[Thanks to Rob Butterworth](http://www.techartblog.com/tips/visual_studio_edit_files_prebuild)

Comment: thank you very much!! sorry that I did not mention it before - but my application is a silverlight application. my web.config file does not recognize the "PropertyGroup" tag...
Do you have any idea?

Comment: it is not a web.config, it is .csproj file. And PropertyGroup with everything except `<UseHostCompilerIfAvailable>false</UseHostCompilerIfAvailable>` should already be in place. You need to add this for all combinations of platforms(x86, x64, AnyCPU, etc.) and modes (Release,Debug, etc.) you have in there

Comment: My solution contains multi projects do i need to do this to all .csproj files or only to the .csproj file in the main project?

Comment: Only for projects that require files to be changed in pre build event

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunately, running with an asp .net core application. I'll see if i can find a workaround.

Comment: @bnns Are you changing the .csproj file? If I change the .cs files, it works. If I change the .csproj file, it fails.